# Use LINQ to make a table using alternative addresses from two tables

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq

I'm trying to build a single data table from two sql tables. I'd like to use a secondary table to merge the second table into the first on the fly? My current code skips records without an alternative address.

The goal would be to return a table that looks like this:

```
    Dim db As New DataClassesDataContext
    Dim buildingTable = From b In db.Buildings
         Join s In db.States
         On b.StateId Equals s.StateId
         Join a In db.Building_Alternate_Addresses
         On b.BuildingId Equals a.BuildingId
         Where b.Active = True
         Order By b.Address1
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: `Where` should always be before an `OrderBy`

Comment: Did you try Joining in the alternate address table before the state table?

Comment: I did not. Let me try that now. Still only gives me a list of buildings that have alternative addresses.

Comment: Try some thing like "from lst1 in TXs
       join lst2 in TYs on lst1.ID equals lst2.ID into yG
       from y1 in yG.DefaultIfEmpty()
       select new { X = lst1, Y =y1 }"

Comment: @Landmine: Don't forget to award the bounty if a solution worked for you ;]

Comment: Apologize! Thank you for this reminder and your help with my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't written VB.NET in a while, but unless I have terribly misunderstood something, you're trying to do a left join between `Building` and `Building_Alternate_Address`, in which case you should be able to do it like this, provided `Building_Alternate_Address` only contains rows with non-null values for `Address2`:

```
from b in Building
from baa in Building_Alternate_Address
              .Where(Function(x as Building) 
                       return x.BuildingId == b.BuildingId 
                     End Function)
              .DefaultIfEmpty()
where b.Active
orderby b.Address1
select New With {
  .BuildingId = b.BuildingId,
  .Address1 = b.Address1,
  .Address2 = baa.Address2,
  .City = b.City,
  .StateId = b.StateId,
  .ZipCode = b.ZipCode,
  .NickName = b.NickName,
  .Active = b.Active
}
```

Comment: What am I saying? Talk about assuming the result!  Let's roll that back to my original answer, shall we?